# Prove the Lebesgue measure of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2}|(A-C)\wedge (B-C)|$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm new to this site so tell me if this question is written wrong.

Given a triangle with vertex's A,B,C in $\mathbb{R}^2$, prove that the Lebesgue measure is equal to triangle is $\frac{1}{2}|(A-C)\wedge (B-C)|$, where $|(a, b)\wedge (c, d)|=|ad-cb|$. The theorems we have at this point at things likes translation in-variance, non-negativity, finite additivity and the like, and that the graph of a continuous function on a box is measurable. I used the latter to prove that the measure exists at all, but I can't seem to figure out how exactly to evaluate it. I have tried to break it up into smaller triangles, but have not figured out how to merge the absolute value signs.

Could anyone show me how to do this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Can't you just add two triangles to make a rectangle?

Comment: You could make a parallelogram, which I don't have formula for measuring. I also have not proven in-variance under reflection, which I think would be needed?

Comment: Do you have that the measure of $T(E)$ is $|\det(T)|$ times the measure of $E$, where $T$ is a linear map?

Comment: @JesseMadnick No, sadly the definition is one the page before the exercise. I wish it wasn't. I have been trying in vain for 4 hours, and am beginning to decide if re-driving calculus really would be excessive.

Comment: At this point I have just been using a case by case elimination on different triangles. I tried splitting them in half but couldn't get the formula to behave.